# Wpf binding image file to BitmapImage UriSource in MVVM way

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, uri, bitmapimage

I'm desperatly triying to bound an image (which is located in a subdirectory of application installation directory).
I'm Using MVVM and .Net 3.5, is'ts easy to find the image path and return either a String, an Uri or a Bitmap in a property and use it in the xaml.

I tryied all these three formats to bind to UriSource in Images.Resources, but none of them worked.
I tried also to bound the UriSource with a String property with a Converter, no luck!

No image is displayed.

Is it possible to achieve that ? Then what am I missing ?

xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_FamilyTree}">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <behaviours:BindableTreeViewSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding TreeViewSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="ExpandingImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Closed}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Open}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style> 
   </TreeView.Resources>
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_Items}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,3,0" Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}">
               <Image.Resources>
                  <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="{Binding OpenFolderPath, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}"/>
                  <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="{Binding OpenFolderPath, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}" />
               </Image.Resources>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Viewmodel :

```
private string myOpenFolderPath;
public ItemListVM()
{
   myOpenFolderPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\images\Icon_Open.png";
   if (!File.Exists(myOpenFolderPath))
      myOpenFolderPath = String.Empty;
}

public string OpenFolderPath
{
   get { return Path.GetFullPath(myOpenFolderPath); }
}
```

Converter :

```
public class UriConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return new Uri(value.ToString());
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
   }
 }
```

I tried the same with an Uri Property with a right Converter which is returning an Uri, no more luck!

EDIT :
here is the solution:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_FamilyTree}">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <behaviours:BindableTreeViewSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding TreeViewSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="ExpandingImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DataContext.ClosedFolderPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenFolderPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style> 
   </TreeView.Resources>
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_Items}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,3,0" Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: It is unclear what your actual problem is. You say that it is "*easy to find the image path and return either a String, [or] an Uri*". That is exactly what you should do, expose a view model property of type string or Uri, and bind the Image`s Source property to that view model property. Built-in type conversion will automatically create an ImageSource.

Comment: When it comes to binding a the UriSource property of a BitmapImage, the source property must be an Uri, but you would usually not do that at all.

Comment: <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="{Binding UriProperty}"/>  <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="{Binding StringProperty, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}} }"/> doesn't work, I got an error "Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set."

Comment: It does work if you do it right. We can't tell if you did.

Comment: I made some edits with more code

Comment: Your ImageConverter does not return an Uri. Besides that, it is totally pointless to use a BitmapImage resource here. Better directly bind the Image.Source property. You would not need a Converter at all, due to built-in type connversion (as already said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither a BitmapImage resource nor a Binding Converter is needed.

This works out of the box, due to built-in type conversion from `string` to
`ImageSource`:

```
<Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding OpenedFolderPath}"/>
```

In the ItemTemplate of the TreeView this Binding will not work, because it doesn't have the expected DataContext. You would write

```
<Setter Property="Source" 
    Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenedFolderPath,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"/>
```

---

Besides that, a converter for the `UriSource` property of a BitmapImage would have to return an Uri, not another BitmapImage:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new Uri(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I already tired your solution, and tried it again to be sure. None of this is working in this context. The only working solution actualy is to embed the images as resource and write the xaml like this : <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="Images/Icon_Open.png" />

Comment: Is the image file really in a subfolder relative to your application's startup folder? Or are you asking about an assembly rersource, i.e. a file embedded in the assembly (the executable) file? Did you try a relative file path instead of an absolute path created from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory?

Comment: If the file is supposed to be an assembly resource, its Build Action must be set to Resource, and you would load it from a Resource File Pack URI like `pack://application:,,,/Images/Icon_Open.png`. In XAML you could then simply write `<Image Source="Images/Icon_Open.png"/>`. But then, why are you asking about data binding at all?

Comment: I'm on this since 4 days, so be sure that I tried all your advices. The original problem is to bind an image which is located in a subfolder of the application's startup folder. I don't get any error but the image is not displayed. I tried another way and put the image in assembly resource and then indeed <Image Source="Images/Icon_Open.png"/> works but this is not answering the question. I wonder why Binding is not working, this why I posted my question. The image is really in a subfolder because I use it elsewhere in xaml code and it work, it's only in this Treeview context that is not work

Comment: Ok, the problem is of course that the DataContext of a TreeViewItem is different from that of the parent view. `{Binding OpenFolderPath, ...}` will hence not work there, but you should have seen a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application. It is however unclear why you have these data bindings at all. Assuming the file names are fixed, you could just write `<Image Source="./Images/Icon_Open.png"/>`

Comment: Anyway, see the edited answer for how to write the Binding in the ItemTemplate.  If you keep the BitmapImage resources, move them out of the ItemTemplate into the Resources of the TreeView or the MainWindow. There your Binding would have worked.

Comment: Argh! you're totaly right about the DataContext. I'm sometimes stupid... Thanks a lot!